# Training RNNs for learning sequential probability distributions

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, probability-distribution

I am interested in learning probability distributions with an RNN. I have attached some handwritten sketches to help explain.

1. Imagine a circuit, and I can measure certain objects from this circuit. The circuit is specified by elements in a vector b.
2. The outputs of the circuit can be measured sequentially (ie: first object 1, object2,...). There are 6 possible measurements that these objects can take which I will call a. In the code below these are encoded first one hot encoding `"0": [1,0,0,0,0,0]` etc...
3. I want to develop an RNN that can predict the probability distribution of P(a1 | b). Then the next would be P(a2 | a1, b) etc. Please refer to my RNN sketch. the output vectors of the RNN for the decoding part would represent probability distributions.

I have implemented code for this strategy below, and am trying to get it to memorize a very simple dataset where object 1 is 50% 0 and 50% 1 and object 2 is always 1. I anticipate this should be able to converge to 0, but if you run it, you find it keeps getting stuck with a loss that is not zero. I am unable to find the structural problem in my code.

Are there any conceptual issues or major implementation errors within this code?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader


# Data (example with 4 measurements)
# these lets say represent the "parameters" of the circuit we are testing
circuit_params = np.array([[0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6] for i in range(4)])

measurement_samples = np.array([[[1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0]],
                                [[0,1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0]],
                                [[1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0]],
                                [[0,1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0,0]]])

# Convert numpy arrays to PyTorch tensors
circuit_params_tensor = torch.tensor(circuit_params, dtype=torch.float32)
measurement_samples_tensor = torch.tensor(measurement_samples, dtype=torch.float32)

# RNN Model
class EncoderDecoderRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(EncoderDecoderRNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.encoder_rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.decoder_rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=output_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, encoder_input, decoder_input):
        _, encoder_hidden = self.encoder_rnn(encoder_input)
        encoder_hidden = encoder_hidden.repeat(1, encoder_input.size(0), 1)
        decoder_output, _ = self.decoder_rnn(decoder_input, encoder_hidden)
        output = self.output_layer(decoder_output)
        return output

# Hyperparameters
input_size = 4 # how many used to describe average
hidden_size = 32 # hidden states internel to RNN
output_size = 6 # Number of possible measurement outputs (1 - 6) of qubits
learning_rate = 0.01 # learning rate of the RNN
num_epochs = 50 # repeats over the dataset
batch_size = 2  # Number of data points (one is: [circuit description] + [data element])

# Instantiate the model
model = EncoderDecoderRNN(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Preparing inputs and outputs for the model
encoder_input = circuit_params_tensor

# Number of measurement samples can vary, we dynamically adjust the decoder input
num_measurements = measurement_samples_tensor.size(1)
#print("num_measurements", num_measurements)

decoder_input = torch.zeros(encoder_input.size(0), num_measurements, output_size)  # Adjusted shape

# Create a TensorDataset to hold your inputs and targets
# this groups the dataset like: (tensor([0.2000, 0.4000, 0.7000, 0.6000]), tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]))
dataset = TensorDataset(circuit_params_tensor, measurement_samples_tensor)

# Create a DataLoader to handle batching
# this batches the data into the RNN
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in dataloader:
        # Unpack the batch data
        encoder_batch_input, decoder_batch_target = batch
        
        # Prepare decoder input (adjusting the shape for batch and measurements)
        decoder_batch_input = torch.zeros_like(decoder_batch_target, dtype=torch.float32)
        
        # Forward pass
        output = model(encoder_batch_input, decoder_batch_input)
        
        # Calculate the loss
        loss = criterion(output, decoder_batch_target)
        
        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
    if (epoch+1) % 1 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')
```

For visualizing the output (repeatedly measuring to get a distribution), you can visualize it with this code to see that it is not working.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

column_averages = np.mean(measurement_samples, axis=0)
num_qubits, num_states = column_averages.shape

single_circuit_param = torch.tensor([[0.2000, 0.4000, 0.7000, 0.6000]], dtype=torch.float32)

def take_multiple_measurements(model, circuit_param, num_qubits, num_measurements):
    measurements = torch.zeros((num_measurements, num_qubits))
    for i in range(num_measurements):
        measurements[i] = take_measurement(model, circuit_param, num_qubits)
    return measurements

def take_measurement(model, circuit_param, num_qubits):
    with torch.no_grad():
        # Initialize the input for the first qubit
        qubit_input = torch.zeros(1, num_qubits, output_size)
        
        # This will store the measurements for all qubits
        measurement = torch.zeros(num_qubits, dtype=torch.long)
        
        for qubit_idx in range(num_qubits):
            # Get the probability distribution of the current qubit given the circuit_param and previous qubits
            qubit_probs = model(circuit_param, qubit_input).squeeze(0)[qubit_idx]
            qubit_probs_softmax = nn.functional.softmax(qubit_probs, dim=-1)
            
            # Sample a value for the current qubit based on the probability distribution
            qubit_state = torch.multinomial(qubit_probs_softmax, 1).item()
            measurement[qubit_idx] = qubit_state
            
            # Update the input for the next qubit
            qubit_input[0, qubit_idx, :] = 0  # Reset the previous state
            qubit_input[0, qubit_idx, qubit_state] = 1.0  # Set the new state
            
        return measurement

# Function to get the distributions for each qubit after multiple measurements
def get_qubit_state_distributions(measurements, num_states):
    num_measurements, num_qubits = measurements.shape
    distributions = torch.zeros((num_qubits, num_states))
    
    for qubit_idx in range(num_qubits):
        for state in range(num_states):
            distributions[qubit_idx, state] = torch.sum(measurements[:, qubit_idx] == state) / num_measurements
    
    return distributions.numpy()

# Take multiple measurements
num_measurements = 100
num_states = 6  # Assuming there are 6 possible states (0 through 5)
measurements = take_multiple_measurements(model, single_circuit_param, num_qubits, num_measurements)

# Calculate the distributions
distributions = get_qubit_state_distributions(measurements, num_states)

x = np.arange(num_states)  # x-coordinates for the bar chart

# Plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_qubits, 1, figsize=(10, 8))

for i in range(num_qubits):
    axes[i].bar(x - 0.2, distributions[i], width=0.4, label='Measured Distribution')
    axes[i].bar(x + 0.2, column_averages[i], width=0.4, label='Average Prediction')
    axes[i].set_title(f'Qubit {i+1}')
    axes[i].set_xticks(x)
    axes[i].set_xticklabels([f'State {j}' for j in range(num_states)])
    axes[i].legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]